# How does Linux's mv work internally?

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems

I know in Linux, if we want to rename a folder from `f_old` to `f_new`, we can run:

```
mv f_old f_new
```

But this command actually confuses me. Does the system copy all stuff inside `f_old`, paste it to new folder `f_new` and delete `f_old` at last? Or does it just rename `f_old` to `f_new`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nothing gets copied or moved if the source and destination are on the same partition.  Various inode components get manipulated, that's all.  If the source and destination are different then you will see a physical copy and delete.

Edit -

Note that it is the **directory entries** that are manipulated. This is a different thing from the inode.

Comment: Note: the name is **not** in the inode, but in the directory entry/entries. In the inode, *at most* the ->ctime can be changed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the discussion.

Comment: @Cosmoandcat You ticked the wrong answer. Inode contents are *not* changed (with a possible exception for ctime), except when the move crosses device boundaries.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for reminding:) But this answer and the following discussion did help me understand the issue. Maybe jmf1205 could edit his/her post so that this won't confuse the others?

Comment: Maybe it helped you, but it is completely *wrong* . @hek2mgl did correct his answer to something usable and deserves the credit for that. SO is not about the discussion, but about the (correct) answers.

Answer (score 10):

As long as the target location is on the same partition (filesystem) as the source, no data will get moved or even touched. Only the name in the directory entry gets changed.

If the target is on a separate partition, the data will first get copied to the target and then removed from source.

Comment: Note: the name is **not** in the inode, but in the directory entry/entries.

Answer (score 5):

This is covered in the full manual, which `man mv` explains how to get:

```
   The  full  documentation  for mv is maintained as a Texinfo manual.  If
   the info and mv programs are properly installed at your site, the  comâ
   mand

          info coreutils 'mv invocation'
```

This is also available online here: https://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/mv

> mv can move any type of file from one file system to another. Prior to
>   version 4.0 of the fileutils, mv could move only regular files between
>   file systems. For example, now mv can move an entire directory
>   hierarchy including special device files from one partition to
>   another. It first uses some of the same code that's used by cp -a to
>   copy the requested directories and files, then (assuming the copy
>   succeeded) it removes the originals. If the copy fails, then the part
>   that was copied to the destination partition is removed. If you were
>   to copy three directories from one partition to another and the copy
>   of the first directory succeeded, but the second didn't, the first
>   would be left on the destination partition and the second and third
>   would be left on the original partition.